# Goroutine gives error

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to poll a website multiple times but I get:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>
> [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x400cca]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://site-centos-64:8080/examples/abc1.jsp",
}

type HttpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
}
var ch = make(chan *HttpResponse, 1000) // buffered

func abc(i int){
        for _, url := range urls {
                resp, err := http.Get(url)
                resp.Body.Close()
                ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }
}
func asyncHttpGets(urls []string) []*HttpResponse {
    responses := []*HttpResponse{}
    for i:=0;i<1000;i++{
        go abc(i)
    }
    for {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            responses = append(responses, r)
            if len(responses) == 1000 {
                return responses
            }

        }
    }

    return responses

}

func main() {
    results := asyncHttpGets(urls)
    for _, result := range results {
        fmt.Printf("%s status: %s\n", result.url,
            result.response.Status)
    }
}
```

Works absolutely fine when I do it for 500 times.

Answer (score 1):

The go `stacktrace` contains which line of your code caused the panic. There are probably a lot of goroutines running but you can grep for your filename.
I'd assume that you have some connection issues with your server.

Proper handling of `err` in your `abc` function should tell you more.
In case of an error, don't call `resp.Body.Close()`. And in your `main` function `result.response.Status` won't work either.